# Disabling text box on check/uncheck of checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following  code on my web page:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" id="test" /> This is test
<br />
<div id="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />This ia another test <br />
  <input type="text" id="test2" /> This is a different test<br />
</div>

<script>
  $('#test').on('change', function() {
    const isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

    $('#test1').toggleClass('disableSection', isChecked);

    $('#test1 input[type="checkbox"]')
      .attr('disabled', isChecked)
      .prop('checked', false);

    $('#test1 input[type="text"]').val('');
  });
</script>
```

on the click of checkbox "test", I want to disable and enable the checkbox "test1" and clear out and disable the input box . I want same thing to be true when the page loads and checkbox "test" is already checked. I was able to successfully disable and enable the check box and clear the text box on click of "test" check box, but if the checkbox "test" is already checked on retrieval then the checkbox "test2" is disabled, but user can type anything in the text box. How can I prevent that? below is my code for disabling and clearing out the checkbox with Id "test2" and textbox with Id "test3" which works fine.

I tried to write this code in order to disable the text box when I retrieve the already checked value of "test" check box, but this is letting the text box to be disabled forever even if I uncheck "test check

```
 <script>
   if ($('#test').is(':checked')) {
     $('#test1 input[type="text"]')
       .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
 </script>
```

Comment: can't you trigger the checked event again on load instead of that?

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose. Use margin or padding with a custom CSS class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that handles what happens when the element is checked or unchecked and call it at the `change` event of the checkbox, but also on the document load event.

```js
function handleCheckboxState() {
  const isChecked = $('#test').is(':checked');
  $('#test1 input').prop('disabled', isChecked);
  $('#test1').toggleClass('disableSection', isChecked);
  if (isChecked) {
    $('#test1 input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    $('#test1 input[type="text"]').val('');
  }
}


// handle manual change
$('#test').on('change', handleCheckboxState);
// handle initial state
$(document).ready(handleCheckboxState);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="checkbox" id="test" /> This is test
<br />
<div id="test1">
  <input type="checkbox" id="test1" />This ia another test <br />
  <input type="text" id="test2" /> This is a different test<br />
</div>
```